# Bootstrap 3 Tooltip - Flicking on MouseOut... Happening if it is inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using Bootstrap 3 and showing "**Tooltip**" onMouseOver which is working as expected. But whenever I am moving out the cursor, screen is flickering.

### HTML:

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Lorem ipsum">
Mouse Over
</div>
```

### Script Initialization:

```
<!-- Tooltip -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>
<!-- /Tooltip -->
```

**I have tried with below options as well:**

```
<script>...</script>
<script language="javascript">...</script> etc...
```

And also changing the script tag **inside head element**, **inside body tag, outside body tag** doesn't helped to achieve my desired result!

Comment: which browser? here it works perfectly in Firefox 33.1

Comment: also which styles did you append to the div?

Comment: Hi @VDesign.. I am using Google Chrome and onMouseOver of help icon, I am showing the "Tooltip" content

Comment: do have a site running where we can check this issue?

Comment: Actually I am devloping in my local :(

Answer (score 0):

try adding `data-container="body"`

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Lorem ipsum" data-container="body">
Mouse Over
</div>
```

Comment: this is also not helping for me :( ... Is anything to do with iFrame? while I am using the Tooltip inside iFrame

Answer (score 0):

I was having exact similar problem..

Solved by changing `animate.css` class properties:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
```

to

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
animation-fill-mode: none;
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following line worked for me:

```
data-container="body" data-placement="right"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.